# Facebook Login Error : INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am developing an android app with Facebook login, On Facebook developer console under the same account, I created 2 apps with different package names.

1 for development purpose and another for testing purpose.
I configured my testing app with testing Facebook app ID, it worked fine.

When I run my development app with Facebook app ID, I am getting an Error :

> "Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER."

How can I sort this issue, Please help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

please chage your provider for both apps. you can not given same facebook id for both app.

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1140422536021372"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: I have 2 separated Facebook ID for both application